# Python formatting spacing issue?

Tags: python, formatting

So I am having this problem with the Python formatting where the sign in front of a number is taking a space up and is misaligning all of the numbers I want to present. In addition, the positive signs are not showing up as they should be.

Here is an example of my code:

```
number1 = 23.12312312
number2 = -31.3131313
number3 = 63.1335

number4 = 12.323
number5 = 23.1111
number6 = 14.5555

print("{0:<15}    {1:+>3.6f}   {2:+>3.6f}".format(number1, number2, number3))
print("{0:<15}    {1:+>3.6f}   {2:+>3.6f}".format(number4, number5, number6))
print("{0:<15}    {1:+>3.6f}   {2:+>3.6f}".format(number1, number2, number3))
```

Output:

```
23.12312312        -31.313131   63.133500
12.323             23.111100   14.555500
23.12312312        -31.313131   63.133500
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Let's just pick on one number.  Study these until the light dawns ;-)

```
>>> x = 23.12312312
>>> print "{:3.6f}".format(x)
23.123123
>>> print "{:10.6f}".format(x)
 23.123123
>>> print "{:11.6f}".format(x)
  23.123123
>>> print "{:+11.6f}".format(x)
 +23.123123
```

The number before the `.` is the **total** width of the output field, not the number of digits before the decimal point.  Your `3` is way too small.

And there's usually no need for `>` - most things right-justify by default.  If you have to use it, put the `+` after `>`, not before `>`.  Good enough?